# Rename a column in a table using php

Tags: php

I need to change a column name when I call a table in a function

```
<?php $ordertype = array("ASC", "DESC");?>
```

How can I substitute "ASC" and "DESC" with another word when the code uses ASC and DESC as variables?

Comment: Think we might a little more context. How's the code being pulled in, do you have the rest of the code this applies to?

Comment: i need to change displayed words momentarily but i can rename the columns so i need an idea like alias or something like this : "name" as " another name"

Comment: Could provide sql code?

Comment: just i need to replace ASC and DESC with other words but ASC and DESC are used as a variables in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$ordertype[$newkey] = $ordertype[$oldkey];
unset($ordertype[$oldkey]);
```